# SCRIPT5018: SCRIPT5018: Unexpected quantifier - What alternative to contentDisposition.match() for IE?

Tags: javascript

I am having an error with a regular expression in Microsoft Edge that does not show up in Chrome.

In Microsoft Edge this line:

```
const fileNameMatch = contentDisposition.match(/(?<=filename=).*/);
```

Show this error:

```
SCRIPT5018: SCRIPT5018: Unexpected quantifier
```

Apparently JavaScript RegEx lookbehinds are not supported in some browser versions, any idea what would be a compatible form of this line that could be supported in most browsers please?

```
 const fileNameMatch = contentDisposition.match(/(?<=filename=).*/);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please always reduce your example to an [MCVE]. If the only problem is with the regular expression, including all the extra code makes it that much harder to read and understand your question.

Comment: ok, I will remember from next time. On other forums, I get shouted at when I do not put enough data lol.....confusing.

Comment: You would get "shouted at" here too, if you didn't include enough code. But your question is *exclusively* about the regex, none of the other code is remotely relevant.